# Can we have a Non-rectangular window in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I thought it may be usefull to have a smaller window display other buffer's information in a
bigger window which we're working on.

Here is an illustration:

[image: an illustration]

Can we achieve this in emacs? I googled and looked at the emacs lisp manual, but get nothing.

Comment: Your screenshot is rectangular, so your question is not sufficiently descriptive of what you want to achieve.  It looks like a simple split-window-vertically and split-window-horizontally.  Just drag your mouse on the window edges to readjust the size of the window.  When you see that this is possible, then you can begin to explore window-height and window-width settings.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Change-Window.html

Comment: I don't think we can achieve this effect through split. As you said,after split-window-vertically and split-window-horizontally we finally get 4 window. But as the picture said, I only want a small window on the top of a big window in the right-left corner

Comment: You can have a 3-window split. There's no use for the top-right corner in your image anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(defun my-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (make-frame '((width . 22)
                (height . 22)
                (minibuffer . nil))))
```

Comment: This is close to my needs, but can't we use window instead of frame to implement this?

Comment: No. Emacs lets you split Emacs windows or create frames of pretty much any rectangular shape & size. Nothing more.